# Should contain atleast using Robotframework

Tags: automation, robotframework, rpa

Created a list where in `@{test} XTEAMK01, KKTEAM01, XTEAMO01, KKTEAM02, XJSTEAMD00, KKTEAM03` and then I want to get the following values that start with "KK"
`KKTEAM01, KKTEAM02,KKTEAM03`

Comment: Do you want to filter the list and get all elemetns that begins with "KK"?

Comment: By removing the Python tag, you have invalidated all answers given below.  Are you sure you wanted to do this?

Comment: no I didn't invalidated but for now i have to achieve it on RBF Apologies Tim. I might use this on my next project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @WindCheck you can format the code to work in robot. This code will produce the result you want.

```
***Variables***
@{test}     XTEAMK01    KKTEAM01    XTEAMO01    KKTEAM02    XJSTEAMD00    KKTEAM03  
*** Test Cases ***   
Example                
    ${x}=    Evaluate    [item for item in ${test} if item.startswith("KK")]
    Log    ${x}
```

alternatively you can use the other answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [startwith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). Here it is used with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
In [1]: l = ["XTEAMK01", "KKTEAM01", "XTEAMO01", "KKTEAM02", "XJSTEAMD00", "KKTEAM03"]

In [2]: [x for x in l if x.startswith("KK")]
Out[2]: ['KKTEAM01', 'KKTEAM02', 'KKTEAM03']
```

Comment: apologies for the confusion guys, currently working it on robotframework. I think this approach is more on a python.

Comment: No worries, but you're outside my wheelhouse now. Good luck.

Comment: did try it and it. now i have to apply it on RBF

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list compreenhension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

```
kk_list = [item for item in full_list if item.startswith("KK")]
```

Comment: apologies for the confusion guys, currently working it on robotframework. I think this approach is more on a python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension:

```py
inp = ["XTEAMK01", "KKTEAM01", "XTEAMO01", "KKTEAM02", "XJSTEAMD00", "KKTEAM03"]
output = [x for x in inp if x[:2] == 'KK']
print(output)  # ['KKTEAM01', 'KKTEAM02', 'KKTEAM03']
```

Or, using regex for a more flexible option:

```py
inp = ["XTEAMK01", "KKTEAM01", "XTEAMO01", "KKTEAM02", "XJSTEAMD00", "KKTEAM03"]
output = [x for x in inp if re.search(r'^KK', x)]
print(output)  # ['KKTEAM01', 'KKTEAM02', 'KKTEAM03']
```

Comment: Probably a lot slower to use regex in this case.

Comment: @theherk Agreed...for this exact case.  Should the complexity of the pattern change, regex might be a better option though.

Comment: apologies for the confusion guys, currently working it on robotframework. I think this approach is more on a python.

Comment: Thank you. This is working now on my end but im having difficulties applying it on RBF. this is very useful and convert dynamically to fetch json objects with different files and ids.

Was uing the regex one

Answer (score 1):

You can use robot's [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation-1) to do a list comprehension:

```
log  matches: ${{[x for x in $test if x.startswith('KK')]}}
```

Or, you can use [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) to do the same list comprehension in a slightly more readable format:

```
@{matches}=   Evaluate  [x for x in $test if x.startswith('KK')]
```